# Can C*-algebras be characterized among Banach *-algebras by the spectral radius?

Tags: reference-request, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $(A,\,^\ast,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$ be a Banach $\ast$-algebra with the property that $\lVert a \rVert^2=\rho(a^\ast a)$ holds for all $a\in A$, 
where $\rho(x)$ denotes the spectral radius of an element $x\in A$.

**Is $(A,\,^\ast,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$ then a $C^\ast$-algebra?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated to include Nik Weaver's correction / improvement from the comments.]

I think this follows from the spectral radius formula:

$$\left\| a \right\|^2 = \rho(a^*a) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left\| (a^*a)^k \right\|^{1/k} \leq \left\| a^*a \right\| \leq \left\| a^* \right\| \left\| a \right\|$$

This gives $\left\| a \right\|^2 \leq \left\| a^* \right\| \left\| a \right\|$, implying $\left\| a \right\| \leq \left\| a^* \right\|$.  Applying the same argument to $a^*$ we get $\left\| a \right\| = \left\| a^* \right\|$, so the inequality above becomes:

$$\left\| a \right\|^2 \leq \left\| a^* a \right\| \leq \left\| a \right\|^2$$

which yields the C* identity, as desired.

(The inequalities above follow from the Banach algebra axiom $\left\| ab \right\| \leq \left\| a \right\| \left\| b \right\|$.)

Comment: I think you need to say a little more ... first use $\|a^*a\| \leq \|a^*\|\|a\|$ in your displayed line to get $\|a\| \leq \|a^*\|$, then $\|a\| = \|a^*\|$ by symmetry, so $\|a^*a\| \leq \|a\|^2$.

Comment: (Unless you count $\|a\| = \|a^*\|$ as an axiom for "Banach *-algebra" ...)

Comment: Alternatively, if you define the spectral radius as the largest modulus of an element of the spectrum, then $\rho(x)\leq \Vert x\Vert$ by the Neumann lemma and so you can bypass the BG-spectral radius formula

Comment: @NikWeaver You're right - I shouldn't have used $\left\| a^* \right\| = \left\| a \right\|$ without comment.  I wouldn't consider it to be a Banach *-algebra axiom, but your correction fixes the argument anyway.

Comment: @PaulSiegel: I googled it, and found that according to Wikipedia "Some authors include this isometric property in the definition of a Banach *-algebra."